# Group concat with where match against in mysql

Tags: mysql, match, group-concat, against

I'm working on a simple search function with SQL and got stuck. I use GROUP_CONCAT to put all keywords in a single row. The keywords are taken from categories.

*Not all columns are in this example. I've stripped it down*

```
SELECT
  p.id as id,
  p.title as title,
  p.title as company,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT cat.title SEPARATOR " ") as keywords,
  FROM products p
    JOIN product_categories pc ON p.id = pc.product_id
    JOIN categories cat ON pc.category_id = cat.id
    JOIN companies co ON p.company_id = co.id
 WHERE MATCH (p.title) AGAINST ("Test")
 OR MATCH (co.title) AGAINST ("Test")
 GROUP BY p.id
```

`keywords` contains something like `keyword1 keyword2 keyword3`.

The SQL above is working. However, I can't use MATCH AGAINST with a virtual value `keywords` value.

**I've read about what I think is an ugly workaround, to add this:**

```
HAVING keywords LIKE "%keyword1%"
```

LIKE is probably slow and because HAVING is after GROUP BY I can't use OR so HAVING in this case will override the WHERE.

Ideally, I would like to use a MATCH AGAINST on `keywords` as well. So, what are my options?

- Some kind of virtual table?
- Subquery?
- Something else?

I probably need an example code to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't answer the question you asked, but I think adding this condition to the WHERE clause of the query:

```
    OR EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM categories k 
                 WHERE k.id = pc.category_id
                   AND k.title IN ('Test1','Test2')
              )
```

before the `GROUP BY` would eliminate the need to scan the return from `GROUP_CONCAT`, if the specification is to return rows where the category title matches one of the specified search words.

---

If there's not a requirement to actually return the derived `keywords` column in the resultset, I'd avoid the GROUP BY.

```
SELECT p.id AS id
     , p.title AS title
     , p.title AS company
  FROM products p
  JOIN companies co
    ON co.id = p.company_id
 WHERE MATCH (p.title) AGAINST ('Test')
    OR MATCH (co.title) AGAINST ('Test')
    OR EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                  FROM categories k
                  JOIN product_categories pc
                    ON pc.category_id = k.id
                 WHERE pc.product_id = p.id
                   AND k.title IN ('Test1','Test2')
              )
 ORDER BY p.id
```

Comment: Yes, that worked and so far it seems fast (4000 products). For some reason the GROUP_CONCAT only returns the searched word, but I guess it has nothing to to with your code. It would be nice to have the categories in the output as well. But it's strange.

Comment: Maybe the `k.title IN` should be replaced with a MATCH predicate  `MATCH (k.title) AGAINST 'Test'`. But I wouldn't think adding the `OR EXISTS` to the original query (shown in the question) would have any impact on rows being returned for `cat.title` in the `GROUP_CONCAT`.(The second query in the answer doesn't return `cat.title`; that's not available because there's no join `categories` table. I know this answer doesn't answer the question that was asked; it answers a different question.)